# Debug a Telnet connection in C

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

I wrote a simple C function which is connect to a switch (by using Telnet socket), and 
there run various cli-commands and exit.
I want to use with a Cisco and a Edge-Core switch.

With Edge-Core switch this function work fine, but does not work at Cisco, because it hang in the "login" process.

Here is the mentioned C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

char *telnet_switch( char *switch_ip, char *cmd, char cmd_out[] ) {
  char                  buf[5000];
  int                   sock;
  int                   bytes;
  struct sockaddr_in    sw;

  sock = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

  sw.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  sw.sin_port        = htons( 23 );
  sw.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( switch_ip );

  if ( sock < 0 ) {
    perror("Socket creation error!");
    return (cmd_out);
  }

  if ( connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sw, sizeof( sw ) ) < 0 ) {
    perror("Connect process error!");
    return (cmd_out);
  }

  send( sock, "admin\n\r", 7, 0 );
  usleep(250000);
  bytes = recv( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ), 0 );

  printf("Bytes: %d\n", bytes);  // DEBUG MESSAGE 1.

  send( sock, "test\n\r", 6, 0 );
  usleep(250000);
  bytes = recv( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ), 0 );

  printf("Bytes: %d\n", bytes);  // DEBUG MESSAGE 2.

  send( sock, cmd, strlen( cmd ), 0 );
  send( sock, "\n\r", 2, 0 );

  memset( buf, 0, sizeof( buf ) );
  memset( cmd_out, 0, sizeof( cmd_out ) );

  usleep(250000);
  recv( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ), 0 );

  sprintf( cmd_out, buf );

  close( sock );
  return (cmd_out);
}
```

And the main (test) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *telnet_switch( char *, char *, char [] );

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  char cmd_out[1000000];

  telnet_switch("192.168.16.18", "?", cmd_out);
  printf("%s\n", cmd_out);

  exit (0);
}
```

The output at the Edge-Core switch:

```
szpal@testnms:~/tmp$ ./test
Bytes: 35
Bytes: 110
edge-core:/>
General Commands:
-----------------
Help/?: Get help on a group or a specific command
Up    : Move one command level up
Logout: Exit CLI

Command Groups:
---------------
System      : System settings and reset options
IP          : IP configuration and Ping
Port        : Port management
MAC         : MAC address table
VLAN        : Virtual LAN
...
VCL         : VLAN Control List
Debug       : Switch debug facilities

Type '<group>' to enter command group, e.g. 'port'.
Type '<group> ?' to get list of group commands, e.g. 'port ?'.
Type '<command> ?' to get help on a command, e.g. 'port mode ?'.
Commands may be abbreviated, e.g. 'por co' instead of 'port configuration'.
edge-core:/>
Nyomjon meg egy billentyűt...
```

And the output at the Cisco switch:

```
szpal@testnms:~/tmp$ ./test
Bytes: 12
```

So i dont know why it cannot login to the Cisco switch, i tried to increase the 'usleep' timeouts, i tried the '\r\n' chars but no success.

There is a Debug process to solve this problem?

Comment: You never implemented the any protocol. You can't call `recv` and expect it to receive entire telnet-protocol or login messages. It's a TCP function. If you need to read until a prompt or read some number of lines or whatever, you need to write code to do that. You can't use sleeps as a synchronization function -- it will never be reliable. You should also at least look at what 12 bytes you received.

Comment: can you try to print the bytes returned from Cisco router? . You can compare this with the bytes received with regular telnet client. it should give you a clue. Also, which router/switch is this ? Some of the switches tend to give more data before it is ready to receive auth request. I would suggest putting the whole thing in a select loop and keep reading on the socket.

Comment: 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0x020 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0x023 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0x027 <EOF>   This is a Cisco SG220-26 switch.

Comment: what if you use a regular telnet client ? what is the o/p you are getting immediately after the  connect? does this o/p make any sense if you compare with that? Also, put the logic in a select loop and try to wait in recv and see if you get any more data when the connection times out. It will give an idea if the server is waiting for any special sequence.

Comment: @joe, i will try as soon as possible..

Comment: this code is making some assumptions: 1) that the telnet login for the cisco switch is 'admin' with no password. (very unlikely)  2) after establishing the connection,  that everything will be returned in a single/fast reply.  both these assumptions are fraught with error.

Comment: @user3629249, If you look carefully the above code, you can see that the username is 'admin' and the password is 'test' in both switch.. and this way WORK with Edge-Core and Linksys SR2024 switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to troubleshoot ethernet connection problems, I usually turn to Wireshark. I think that if you compare the connection process of your code versus a standard telnet client using Wireshark, you will probably be able to spot what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem with all this code is that you are using the unknown sequence `\n\r` as a line terminator. The specified line terminator in the Telnet protocol is `\r\n`.

Also you don't need to sleep before calling `recv()`. It blocks.